# Python: create new dataframe with quantity of products

Tags: python

I am looking to create a new dataframe with the following information:

- total quantity of each product sold
- total price received (ie. total quantity * unit price)

My dataframe has approx 8,000 distinct products, and is structured similar to the below table.

| product | quantity | unit price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 13.42 |
| b | 5 | 6.54 |
| c | 1 | 9.57 |
| a | 6 | 13.42 |
| b | 3 | 6.54 |

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby`:

```
output = df.groupby("product").agg({"quantity": "sum", "unit price": "first"})
output["total price"] = output["quantity"].mul(output["unit price"])

>>> output
         quantity  unit price  total price
product                                   
a               8       13.42       107.36
b               8        6.54        52.32
c               1        9.57         9.57
```